# Ansible warning that host key has changed, even though I've taken multiple steps to prevent this warning

Tags: ansible, vagrant

I've followed the recommendations I could find to prevent this from happening.  I am using Vagrant, but once the boxes are spun, I'd like to do things with the `ansible` command sometimes.

```
$ grep host_key /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg                                                                                                               
host_key_checking = False

$ grep kafka01 ./inventory
kafka01 ansible_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_port=2231 ansible_user='vagrant' ansible_ssh_private_key_file='/home/me/project/project/.vagrant/machines/kafka01/virtualbox/private_key' ansible_ssh_common_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'

$ export ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False
$ ansible kafka01 -m ping -i ./inventory                                                                                                               

 [WARNING]: Unhandled error in Python interpreter discovery for host kafka01: Failed to connect to the host via ssh: @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  @    WARNING:
REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!  Someone could be eavesdropping on
you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!  It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.  The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:jn5ClU5g566Gsvobf8Xc45DJnIiAllN+RJkg35Nf9KE.  Please contact your system administrator.  Add correct host key in /home/me/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.  Offending ECDSA key
in /home/me/.ssh/known_hosts:19    remove with:    ssh-keygen -f "/home/me/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "[127.0.0.1]:2231"  ECDSA host key for [127.0.0.1]:2231 has changed and you have requested strict
checking.  Host key verification failed.

kafka01 | UNREACHABLE! => {
.....
```

What's going on here?

Edit: No, I don't want to keep deleting the key.  I destroy/build these over and over again.  I want to find the correct, long-term solution.

Comment: `It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.` try to remove the client entry in `/home/me/.ssh/known_hosts`

Comment: ... by the command proposed in the message `ssh-keygen -f "/home/me/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "[127.0.0.1]:2231`

Comment: @msp9011 That's the obvious answer, right?  Problem is after I destroy then rebuild the keys have changed again.  I don't want to keep deleting them.

Comment: @msp9011 only /etc/ansible/

Comment: can u plz share version of ansible

Comment: try adding `UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null` in sshCommonArgs as `ansible_ssh_common_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null'

Answer (score 5):

You can add this in inventory:

```
ansible_ssh_common_args="-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null"
```

It's ignoring check host and setting /dev/null as Known host file.

Comment: Please explain what this will do and remove the spaces at the beginning of the code block

Answer (score 4):

An alternative sintax to `Dilson Rainov`'s answer, more ansible 2.x style (I think).

In your inventory define the host as:

```yml
vagrant-local:
      ansible_host: 192.168.33.10
      ansible_user: vagrant
      ansible_ssh_private_key_file: .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
      UserKnownHostsFile: /dev/null
      StrictHostKeyChecking: no
      ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
```

- `UserKnownHostsFile` causes the check of the host fingerprint on an always empty file (replacing the check inside `~/.ssh/known_hosts`)
- `StrictHostKeyChecking` allows ssh to connect without the user confirming the detected fingerprint from the vagrant host